# Exposing methods to JS on a CAxWindow from a BHO ( C++ )

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, atl, bho

I have this BHO which I successfully exposed method to JS from it using this thread: [Calling BHO method from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815845/calling-bho-method-from-javascript).

When I open a CAxWindow in order to host HTML docs, I'd like to use this exported method but it seems that it doesn't work for that window as well.

I tried to make a custom class like:

```
class Bubble: 
public CAxWindow, 
public IDispEventImpl<1, Bubble, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 0>
{
public:

    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(Bubble)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE , OnDocumentComplete) 
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE , OnDownloadComplete)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2, BeforeNavigate2)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_ONQUIT, OnQuit)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_NAVIGATEERROR, NavigateError)           
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2 , OnNavigateComplete2)
    END_SINK_MAP()
```

To try repeat the process of exposing the methods on document complete but it seems that the event is not being fired.

So basically my question is: is there anyway to expose methods to js on my CAxWindow?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you still interested?

Answer (score 1):

`IDispEventImpl` implements sink interface to handle event methods calls. You cannot extend it with your own additional methods directly. Additionally, JavaScript does not really see this interface from scripting code because it is connected to ActiveX control site, not the scripting engine. `IDispEventImpl` is at all a simplified implementation of `IDispatch` COM interface, reference counter free, suitable for event `IDispatch::Invoke` call on the connection point sink interface.

You need to either implement a type library enabled COM object with `IDispatch` interface (type library is used by scripting engine to discover actual methods), or custom `IDispatch` or `IDispatchEx` interface implementation (yes, this can be implemented directly on `CAxWindow` class as additional base class/interface) handling method name resolution without type library. Then you will pass this object to the scripting engine as [`external`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object or otherwise.